# Android, unexpected xmlns error

Tags: android

on my first debugging app i have error on 'xmlns', that i don't find solution.

Error:`"Type Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag AutoCompleteTextView"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF" 
            android:padding="10dip">

        <!-- World URL-->
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_weight="1"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                              android:id="@+id/url" 
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                              android:text="@string/urllauncher_default_value_textfield" 
                              android:textColor="#000000"   
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                              android:singleLine="true" 
                              android:hint="@string/urllauncher_hint_textfield" 
                              android:inputType="textUri"/>

        <!-- Launch button -->
        <Button android:layout_weight="0" 
                android:id="@+id/button_visit_url"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/urllauncher_button_launch">
        </Button>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and what error exactly says? that you should not override namespaces?

Comment: Error:"Type Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag AutoCompleteTextView"

Comment: Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from `<AutoCompleteTextView ...../>`

Comment: @Selvin you shouldn't answer! it's not an obligation!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`from the following section:

```
                  <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_weight="1"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                              android:id="@+id/url" 
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                              android:text="@string/urllauncher_default_value_textfield" 
                              android:textColor="#000000"   
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                              android:singleLine="true" 
                              android:hint="@string/urllauncher_hint_textfield" 
                              android:inputType="textUri"/>
```

Because the namespace has already been defined in your **LinearLayout**